# How can I run JUnit tests of a Java project from an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin that modify some classes of a Java project (insert or update parts of code, delete or something else), copy these temp classes in a new folder, try to compile them and, if the compilation is successful, run JUnit tests on these modified classes. 
JUnit tests are collected in a .jar file but I'm having some troubles running these tests from my plugin, 'cause the project it works on is in a different workspace. 
Currently I'm able to open this .jar and read all test classes and test methods.
I tried using JUnitCore.run to execute every single test method but I don't understand how I can run these tests from two different workspaces.

```
JUnitCore j = new JUnitCore();
for (String test : Analizer.getTestJar().getTestList())
{
    Request methodReq = Request.method(AllTests.class, test);
    Result res = j.run(methodReq);

    boolean succ = res.wasSuccessful();
    int failure = res.getFailureCount();
    List<Failure> failures = res.getFailures();
}
```

In some other examples I saw that maybe I could use a JUnitWorkbenchLaunchShortcut with a class that extends TestRunListener, but I'm not sure it can help me in this case.

How can I do this?
Is it possibile that this problem exists only during the debug phase of the plugin?
Thank you.